# How do I execute another script using command handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been struggling on this for a while, now but I'm struggling at executing child process JavaScript file.
Basically, I've created a command handler for my discord bot  so, every command has its on file which it executes, which looks like this.

```js
module.exports = {  
  name: 'bot',
    description: "Executes bot.js",
    execute(message, args) {   //I want to execute bot.js in same directory in another folder
      }
}
```

There's another JavaScript in the same directory in another folder called bot.js. I basically want to call that function and execute and bring back a variable.

Unsure how to do that.

Comment: Why not straight away execute that module itself? If anything extra, then just add it in that module. Still anyway for your question, just require the module, and then call then function that executes that part of the file. Make sure the `bot.js` has a function that executes all things that you did.

Comment: "Why not straight away execute that module itself? if anything extra, then just add it in that module."
- Honestly, I was debating myself that I just made things a lot harder I guess. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs has a built-in module called [VM](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedobject_options).